# applying seasons including yearly and half-year in R

Tags: r, function

I know there are answers on here on how to apply seasons to a data frame, my question adds the complexity of adding yearly and half-year when a start to end date doesn't fall within the typical season range

```
dates <- data.frame(StartDate=as.Date(c("01/01/2013","04/01/2013","10/01/2013","06/01/2013"    
,"09/01/2013","05/01/2013"), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),EndDate=as.Date(c("12/01/2013","12/21/2013
","05/25/2014","08/15/2013","11/30/2013","10/01/2013"),format = "%m/%d/%Y"))


StartDate    EndDate
1 2013-01-01 2013-12-01
2 2013-04-01 2013-12-21
3 2013-10-01 2014-05-25
4 2013-06-01 2013-08-15
5 2013-09-01 2013-11-30
6 2013-05-01 2013-10-01
```

I need to write a function that adds a "season" column so my output so I would add a column named season to the existing data frame

```
    StartDate    EndDate  Season
1 2013-01-01 2013-12-01   Yearly
2 2013-04-01 2013-12-21   Yearly
3 2013-10-01 2014-05-25   Half-year
4 2013-06-01 2013-08-15   Summer
5 2013-09-01 2013-11-30   Fall
6 2013-05-01 2013-10-01   Half-year
```

Also, since the dates fall are all over the place I thought it might simplify things if I drop the date and year and applying the function based on the month only and then I converted them to numeric.

```
dates$StartDate <- format(dates$StartDate, "%m")
dates$EndDate <- format(dates$EndDate, "%m")
dates$StartDate <- as.numeric(dates$StartDate)
dates$StartDate <- as.numeric(dates$StartDate)

 StartDate    EndDate
  1            12
  4            12
 10             5
  6             8
  9            11
  5            10
```

Here is the function that I tried to write. My parameters are: if start date equals end date then that's yearly, if end date - start date +1 = 12 then that's yearly, if end date - start date +1 is between 8-11 that's yearly, if end date - start date +1 is greater than or equal to 5 but less than 8 then that's half-year, if end date - start date = 6 that is half-year, and then the season based on 3 month intervals.

If there is an easier way I am open to suggestions.

```
Seasons <- function(dates) 
{
dates$Season <- NULL
for(i in 1:dim(dates)[1])
{
    if(dates$StartDate[i] == dates$EndDate[i]){
        dates$Season[i] <- "Yearly"  
    }
    if(dates$EndDate[i] - dates$StartDate[i] + 1 == 12){
        dates$Season[i] <- "Yearly" 
    }
    if(dates$EndDate[i] - dates$StartDate[i] == 6){
         dates$Season[i] <- "Half Year"
    }
    if(dates$EndDate[i] - dates$StartDate[i] + 1 >= 5 < 8){
        dates$Season[i] <- "Half Year" 
    }
    if(dates$EndDate[i] - dates$StartDate[i] + 1 >= 8 < 12){
        dates$Season[i] <- "Yearly"
    }
    if(dates$StartDate[i] == 12 & dates$EndDate[i] == 2){
        dates$Season[i] <- "Winter"
    }
    if(dates$StartDate[i] == 3 & dates$EndDate[i] == 5){
        dates$Season[i] <- "Spring"
    }
    if(dates$StartDate[i] == 6 & dates$EndDate[i] == 8){
        dates$Season[i] <- "Summer"
    }
    if(dates$StartDate[i] == 9 & dates$EndDate[i] == 11){
        dates$Season[i] <- "Fall"
    }
return(dates)
}
}
```

When I run the function it applies "Summer" to all dates. Also, there are rows that are blank or have no end date which I want to ignore.

I also get the a lot of errors, here are the main ones:

```
Error: unexpected '<' in:
Error in dates$Season[i] <- "Half Year" : object 'i' not found
Error: unexpected '}' in "        }"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you have built should be this way:

```
library(data.table)
Seasons <- function(dates) 
{
  seasons <- rep(NA, nrow(dates))
  for(i in 1:nrow(dates))
  {
    if(is.na(month(dates$StartDate[i])) | is.na(month(dates$EndDate[i]))) next
    if(month(dates$StartDate)[i] == month(dates$EndDate)[i]){
      seasons[i] <- "Yearly"  
    }
    if(abs(month(dates$EndDate)[i] - month(dates$StartDate)[i]) + 1 == 12){
      seasons[i] <- "Yearly" 
    }
    if(abs(month(dates$EndDate)[i] - month(dates$StartDate)[i]) == 6){
      seasons[i] <- "Half Year"
    }
    if(abs(month(dates$EndDate)[i] - month(dates$StartDate)[i] + 1) >= 5 & 
       abs(month(dates$EndDate)[i] - month(dates$StartDate)[i] + 1) < 8){
      seasons[i] <- "Half Year" 
    }
    if(abs(month(dates$EndDate)[i] - month(dates$StartDate)[i]) + 1 >= 8 & 
       abs(month(dates$EndDate)[i] - month(dates$StartDate)[i]) + 1 < 12){
      seasons[i] <- "Yearly"
    }
    if(month(dates$StartDate)[i] == 12 & month(dates$EndDate)[i] == 2){
      seasons[i] <- "Winter"
    }
    if(month(dates$StartDate)[i] == 3 & month(dates$EndDate)[i] == 5){
      seasons[i] <- "Spring"
    }
    if(month(dates$StartDate)[i] == 6 & month(dates$EndDate)[i] == 8){
      seasons[i] <- "Summer"
    }
    if(month(dates$StartDate)[i] == 9 & month(dates$EndDate)[i] == 11){
      seasons[i] <- "Fall"
    }
  }
  return(seasons)
}
```

Then when you run it, it produces:

```
> dates$seasons <- Seasons(dates)
> dates
   StartDate    EndDate   seasons
1 2013-01-01 2013-12-01    Yearly
2 2013-04-01 2013-12-21    Yearly
3 2013-10-01 2014-05-25      <NA>
4 2013-06-01 2013-08-15    Summer
5 2013-09-01 2013-11-30      Fall
6 2013-05-01 2013-10-01 Half Year
```

A few comments about your function:

- `if(dates$EndDate[i] - dates$StartDate[i] + 1 >= 5 < 8` is a syntax error. If you want to check against both `>` and `<` you need to type the expression twice.
- When you deduct one value from another make sure you use the absolute value as for example `5 - 10 + 1 == -4` which is clearly not what you want.
- The third date falls under none of the categories you have created, so you ll need to decide on some new category
- The function above returns a vector of values which I then attach to the original data.frame. I find this a bit clearer for this task.
- Since you have created your own rules it is better to go with your own function as I do not think you can use any of the packages available.
- The function `month` comes from data.table and returns the number of the month of the date.
- In your function `return(dates)` is in the `for-loop` which would cause your  function to stop the for-loop during the first iteration.

Comment: This works on the sample data however when I run it on my actual data set I get the following error 'Error in if (month(FarmMkt$Date1)[i] == month(FarmMkt$Date2)[i]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed' Could it be because there are blank rows in the data set?

Comment: @S.Galleg This means that there are elements (rows) in the Date1 or Date2 columns that are NA (missing values). Use `na.omit` on your data.frame to remove those and try again and it will work `dates <- na.omit(dates)`.

Comment: @S.Galleg Actually I changed the function to handle NAs (the first if statement). If any row has an NA value the output will also be NA.

Comment: That didn't work I received the following error a few times '1: In if (is.na(month(dates$StartDate)) | is.na(month(dates$EndDate))) next :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used' I omitted the rows that are blank or NA and the original code worked. If you want to change it I will vote for your response.

Comment: Yeah sorry it should be `if (is.na(month(dates$StartDate[i])) | is.na(month(dates$EndDate[i]))) next `. I missed the `[i]`